# What are journals for islamic studies publications?

Tags: islamic-scholar, books

In which journals are Islamic studies published.
I have come [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/304645727_AL-GHAZALI%27S_PARENTING_SKILLS_ATTRIBUTES_MODEL_Model_Atribut_Kemahiran_Keibubapaan_al-Ghazali), but was not aware of a journal system in which Islamic studies are published.
In which ones can one subscribe?